# Fail2ban not configuring properly

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I have just installed a fresh version of iptables followed by fail2ban, but fail2ban fails to do anything with iptables and I am stuck with no changes being made, this fail2ban not working properly.

Any help please?
Thanks!

My iptables -L:
    http://pastebin.com/srks3DyH

Comment: What does `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` look like?

Answer (score 4):

Your `iptables -L`-output looks normal, for a fail2ban-setup that haven't detected anything bad going on.

Verify the following:

- is fail2ban running? Run `ps aux | grep fail2ban`, you should see a `fail2ban-server`-process.
- Does `/var/log/fail2ban.log` have any content? (If this file does not exist, check `/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf` for logtarget.)
- Does `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/ssh.conf` exist?
- Does `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables.conf` exist?

If you still can't figure it out, it would be cool if you added the Linux-distribution, and version of fail2ban in use.  You should also provide what kind of attack you want to defend yourself against.  I have assumed ssh brute-force above.

Comment: the log does have some content just saying that it created new jail 'ssh' and some other things for setting that up. All the files do exist.
I am using the latest fail2ban with Ubuntu server 11.04 x64. When I try to purposely get banned on another computer from trying too many failed passwords, it doesnt get me banned.

Comment: How does the failed login attempts look in `/var/log/daemon.log`? What does your `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/ssh.conf` look like?